# Time-series for website traffice analysis aftere adding influencer?

Tags: time-series

On my website (interactivia.ro) I've added a gamification module from CaptainUp. I'm interested to find out how this gamification module influenced my website traffic.

The data extracted from Google Analytics is for an year and for this period I also have (almost) daily interactions from the gamification module, something like this:

https://goo.gl/fFZCJ1

My questions:
- how can I find out the influence (if any) of the gamification module on my website traffic
- is there a step-by-step example (in SPSS)?

Thank you,
Catalin

Comment: You need to have daily data for every day in order to properly handle this problem with parametric time series analysis tools.

Comment: @IrishStat - I do have daily data - see above link. In some days there are no gamification activities, hence 0 in that column

Comment: your data needs to be formed in two columns ; y and x . You need two values for each of the "n" rows where n is the total number of days. Specify the beginning date (row 1) and the ending date (row n)

Comment: here it is [link]https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZLQygQaWeEor9BK6wKDZPyGZ--nr4eBm-WSLAwNrmZk/edit?usp=sharing[/link]

Comment: Just to be sure  ,,,, which series is the response series (y) , the one you are trying to predict based upon the other (x).  What country is this from ? Is there any reason to believe that Y today is influenced by future values of X ?

Comment: I'm trying to see if column B (Google) is influenced by column C (CaptainUp). Please note 2014-9-24 is the date when I implemented CaptainUp and there are no data for this date as it was misleading, based on live tests (outlier)

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what kind of an effect you are looking for, but if you are looking for an increase or a decrease, then I would just plot traffic data as two separate time-series in Excel.  If you see a response, and want to understand if that change is statistically significant, then you will need to combine your data into before and after datasets (e.g., unique visits per day before and after), and then look for a shift in the mean via an ANOVA, t-test, or similar.  All of this should be doable in Excel or any stats package.

Answer (score 0):

I took your 450 values (Y and X ) into AUTOBOX , a piece of software uniquely designed for your problem. In summary , you had significant error variance change requiring Generalized Least Squares VIA the Tsay Test [image] . This lead to the detection of a number of level shifts , significant days-of-the week effects ( and three changes in the daay-of-the-week factors ) and an ARIMA component reflecting period to period and week to week auto-dependency.[image] . The residuals from this model are reasonable [image] and exhibit no [image]autocorrelation . The Actual[image] and Forecast plot is here with the forecasts shown here [image] . A table of forecasts is here [image] . In summary your X variable is important contemporaneously.

Comment: thank you for the model and for Autobox - I didn't know about it.
How do you comment the model from here (same data): https://www.linkedin.com/grp/post/2511642-6032034918089969664?trk=groups-post-b-title

Comment: I visually identified a possible need to consider variance changes due to the graph of the original data and tested for that leading to a different model whereas the standard default for daily data is not to test for variance changes. We will reconsider this default. All models are wrong but both of these models seem useful and have some common features.

Comment: @catalin ... perhaps we should talk to pursue this discussion. you can reach me at my contact telephone number in the US

Comment: @Catalin We both ended up with AR(1) and AR(7) coefficients and  level shifts and day-of-the-week effects.